# How to check activity.isDestroyed() pre API level 17?

Tags: android

activity.isDestroyed() was added in API 17. Prior to that it did not exist. For pre 17 devices how to check if activity is destroyed. Current documentation indicates that activity.isFinishing() returns true while activity is finishing but does not indicate what it returns once the activity has been destroyed.  Does anyone know how to check if activity has been destroyed pre API 17? Come on guys! What did you do in the good old days to check for destroyed activity? FYI, the reason I need to know is FragmentManager will still crash during transaction even allowing stateless loss or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late, I guess, but I think you can use something like

```
if (getActivity().isChangingConfigurations() || getActivity().isFinishing()) {
    //activity is being destroyed, no sense to make a transaction
}
```

isChangingConfigurations() also requires min API level 11, but I guess, you don't need to support devices with lower APIs

Or you can set a flag instanceStateSaved in onSaveInstanceState

```
private boolean instanceStateSaved;

...

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    instanceStateSaved = true;
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

After instance was saved, you can't make a transaction without state loss and you can't show any DialogFragment. So you can check

```
if (instanceStateSaved) {...}
```